# Close reason not visible in review pages on Meta.SciFi.SE

Tags: bug, design

This picture pretty much shows the problem.

[image]

The text is there, and visible when selected, it's just hidden by being on a same-color background.

[image]

Comment: Heh, you were undoubtedly the first person to go through this. `/review` on meta!

Comment: This looks like the same issue as http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/can-we-change-the-font-of-the-new-responses-in-meta-scifi-so-that-it-is-readab and http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/title-for-updated-favorited-question-unreadable

Comment: @NominSim Similar, but not the same.  The two you've suggested are duplicates of each other, but this question is regarding an entirely different element.

Comment: @Iszi Actually both of those posts are regarding different elements as well. The underlying issue however is that there are sections of text on the meta site that have poor formatting that makes them invisible.

Comment: @NominSim Without a screenshot in your question, it's hard to tell that the elements referred to are really different.  Still, these are not "exact duplicates".  While they could be consolidated to one thread, since they are *similar* issues, there is no one fix that will resolve them all - they each need to be fixed in their own part of the site template.

Comment: @Iszi It seems to me that the fix is probably one of just resolving the particular font scheme that each of the areas refer to, but I agree they aren't "exact duplicates", just wanted to put the links to the other questions on here so that whoever eventually comes along to fix them can see each of the areas that have issues, so that they don't fix one without the other.

Comment: So much for [trying to consolidate these into one bug report](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2213/366) :(

Comment: It's quite ironic that the review tool just asked me to decide whether this question is a duplicate, while this question shows the screen-shot of a review prompt to decide if one of *my* previous questions was a duplicate.